Diferencia entre hacer el console.log en la función sin return y hacerle un return a la función con el console.log afuera
Alguien podría explicarme por favor cual es la diferencia entre hacer la función de una manera o la otra, ya que en ambos a mi parecer obtengo el mismo resultado.
function suma(n1,n2) {
    let resultado=n1+n2;
    console.log(resultado);
}
suma(2,2);
function suma2(num1,num2) {
    let resultado=num1+num2;
    return resultado
}
console.log(suma(2,2));


La segunda función tiene una sola responsabilidad que es hacer un cálculo y devolver el resultado. Eso permite que sea reutilizable y se puedan hacer pruebas unitarias más fácilmente. En la mayoría de casos es preferible la segunda.

no, no hay diferencia "programatica", vas a ver el mismo resultado.. pero si, tene en cuenta el comentario anterior...

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Debido a que no implementas clases, OOP, setter y getter; La primera funcion tiene tres responsabilidad: Calcular, guardar e imprimir el resultado. La segunda tiene tres responsabilidades tambien: Calcular, guardar y retornar el resultado.
En cuanto a funcionalidad, el resultado es el mismo, en cuanto a estructura y a un nivel de programacion profesional puede ser cuestionable... ya que dificulta la escalabilidad.
En el siguiente ejercicio podras observar como se implementa cada caracteristica:
class Calculadora {
    constructor() {
        this.operando1 = 0;
        this.operando2 = 0;
        this.resultado = 0;
    }

    // Setter para asignar valores a los operandos
    setOperandos(operando1, operando2) {
        this.operando1 = operando1;
        this.operando2 = operando2;
    }

    // Getter para obtener el resultado
    getResultado() {
        return this.resultado;
    }

    // Método para realizar la suma
    sumar() {
        this.resultado = this.operando1 + this.operando2;
        return this.resultado;
    }
}

// Crear instancia de la clase Calculadora
const calculadora = new Calculadora();

// Establecer operandos
calculadora.setOperandos(2, 2);

// Realizar la suma y obtener el resultado
console.log(calculadora.sumar());

// Obtener y mostrar el resultado
console.log(calculadora.getResultado());

Manejar este nivel de programacion puede ser execivo en este ejemplo, pero en entornos profesionales puede ser un requisito indispensable.
